# how timeToLiveSeconds in Ehcache works with setCreateTime()?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I want to know whether I need to reset the create time of an `Element` by calling `elm.setCreateTime()` to extend the aliveness or just stop worrying about it.

I noticed that the method is marked as deprecated since 1.7, but the author failed to explain why.

please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore mutative methods on `Element` in Ehcache 2.x. They are a legacy and the `Element` type should be considered and used as an immutable thing.

If you need to extend the lifetime of a cache mapping, you need to replace the mapping, which will mean the TTL applies again.
TTI might be another choice, but the semantics are a bit weird in the sense that any hit on the value will extend its lifetime.